# How to handle 500 Internal Server Error with ESRI Silverlight API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, arcgis-rest-api

I have a simple AGS map service. I accidentally specified an invalid SRID explicitly in my Silverlight XAML:

```
<esri:Map x:Name="Map" IsLogoVisible="False">
    <esri:Map.Extent>
        <esri:Envelope XMin="526801.81" YMin="489775.0655" XMax="593105.41" YMax="523904.2045">
            <esri:Envelope.SpatialReference>
                <esri:SpatialReference WKID="3807" />
            </esri:Envelope.SpatialReference>
        </esri:Envelope>
    </esri:Map.Extent>
    <esri:Map.Layers>
        <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer x:Name="MyLayer" ID="MyService" Url="http://localhost/ArcGIS/rest/services/MyService/MapServer" Initialized="MyLayer_Initialized" InitializationFailed="Layer_InitializationFailed" />
    </esri:Map.Layers>
</esri:Map>
```

This results in a RESTful request that looks like this:

```
http://localhost/ArcGIS/rest/services/MyService/MapServer/export?bbox=526801.8125,479254.134305427,593105.4375,534425.146944573&size=1078,897&format=png24&transparent=true&layers=show:0,1&f=image&imageSR=3807&bboxSR=3807
```

This request fails with the following IIS error:

```
Error Summary

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Detailed Error Information

Module  ESRI.RestModule-Integrated
Notification    ResolveRequestCache
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x00000000
```

If I replace the invalid SRID, everything works fine.

Is there any way to get the Silverlight API to report exceptions like this? As it is I have to use Fiddler to find it.

[image]

Comment: what spatial reference does 3807 refer to?

Comment: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3087/

Comment: Typo? 3807 isn't a valid SRID. Do you still have this problem when using 3087?

Comment: -1 For this question to be useful, I think it should be reframed around how to catch a 500 error in Silverlight. I searched a bit but don't see an easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>It doesn't look like Esri supports this spatial ref:</del>

Update: this seems to work:

```
http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=4326&outSR=3087&geometries={"geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint","geometries":[{"x":-82,"y":22}]}
```

I'm also interested in ways to trap a 500 error in silverlight.

**Update:**
If we were working with WCF directly, it appears that [Microsoft provides a way to catch this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
However, since it is Esri's Map control making the calls, it seems like they would need to catch it.  I don't see something for this in the [Map control's list of events](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Map_events.html).  Maybe the Map needs to expose something similar to [Layer.InitializationFailed](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Layer~InitializationFailed_EV.html), that would let us catch these types of http errors without relying on Fiddler.

Comment: What do you mean when you say they don't "support" it? It's a perfectly valid SR.

Comment: I think OP has a typo in the original post. It's 3087, not 3807. This works:  http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=4326&outSR=3087&geometries={%22geometryType%22:%22esriGeometryPoint%22,%22geometries%22:[{%22x%22:-82,%22y%22:22}]}

Comment: @Swingley Doh! You're totally right. But seriously ESRI... how on earth is 500 Internal Server Error the right response to an invalid SRID?

Comment: Don't check this answer if it doesn't really answer your question. Someone from Esri might be more inclined to reply to an unanswered question.